# How many different Strings can I create with the characters of the String *SPEISESTAERKE*?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many different Strings can I create with the characters of the String *SPEISESTAERKE* ?

According to that [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316388/how-many-different-4-letter-words-can-you-create-from-the-characters-of-paral), I have tried the following. Note, that I use all the given characters at once to create all possible combinations:

$2 \times$S, 
$1 \times$P, 
$4 \times$E,
$1 \times$I,
$1 \times$A,
$1 \times$R,
$1 \times$K

$\binom {13}{2} \cdot \binom {11}{1} \cdot \binom {10}{4} \cdot \binom {6}{1} \cdot \binom {5}{1} \cdot \binom {4}{1} \cdot \binom {3}{1} \cdot \binom {2}{1} \cdot \binom {1}{1} = 129 729 600$

Unfortunately this is the wrong answer. The correct solution is $432 432 00$.

**Question**: How can I achieve the correct result?

Comment: Your letter counts are wrong. I see three S's, for example, and a T.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can calculate the easiest case first and then tailor the number for the purpose. We pretend the letters are all different; then, since there are 13 letters, we can obtain $13!$ words. But there are replicate ones. The "S" appears three times and the "E" appears four times. So $13!$ is $3! \times 4!$ times the number required! So the required number is 
$$
\frac{13!}{3!4!}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

alternative answer - with correctly counted letters:

$\binom {13}{3} \cdot \binom {10}{4} \cdot \binom {6}{1} \cdot \binom {5}{1} \cdot \binom {4}{1} \cdot \binom {3}{1} \cdot \binom {2}{1} \cdot \binom {1}{1}  = 432 432 00$

Comment: Note that this calculation is known as a [multinomial coefficient])(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients) and often notated $\binom{13}{3,4,1,1,1,1,1,1}$.